# Multinomial distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, approximate-inference

[image]

I want to show this theorem. here you get the details of it. http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/wasserman-multinomial.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1V6yB5-100XSzk6vt5cgNzV0PHdT9qJ8mwxEGplV1q-QiwgP3-Z7i0jvA

where $p$ is multinomial distribution. I show that using MLE that $\hat{p}=x/n$ . Then I used the central limit theorem but not sure. Also, after that, I define $Y=\sqrt{n}(\hat{p}-p)$ . Now, I'm stuck on completely how can I show that $Y^TDY$ follows chi-square with df=$(k-1)$ , where $D=\text{diag}(p_1^{-1},........,p_k^{-1})$ . Give me a hand, please.

Comment: What does the $\rightsquigarrow$ symbol mean ? I guess it's not mentioned in the document which you've uploaded.

Comment: It means convergence in distribution.